# cheapest blender for hot liquids

Tags: equipment, shopping, blender

What is the cheapest "jar" (i.e. not immersion) blender that will survive daily blending of hot liquids (100 degrees celsius / 212 degrees fahrenheit)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about shopping recommendations.  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your standard Oster style blender will do fine. That particular blender has a great advantage in that replacement parts and "upgrade" parts are super easy to find. [Oster](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_st?keywords=blender&qid=1381999212&rh=n%3A1055398%2Ck%3Ablender%2Cp_89%3AOster&sort=price) I still use an Oster blender that belonged to my grandmother. Frequent blending of boiling hot liquids will wear out the o-ring, but o-rings are cheap and easy to replace. You can get a perfectly good old Oster at a thrift store for a song.

Read this too: [How can I safely use a blender with hot liquids?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5712/how-can-i-safely-use-a-blender-with-hot-liquids?rq=1)

Here's good info too from About.com: "Blend hot liquids carefully, starting on lowest speed; leave lid cap off for steam to escape and fill the jar only half full, allowing more room for expansion. You may need to use a hot pad while holding down the lid during operation."

Knowing in advance that you want to blend hot liquids, you might want to choose a glass "heat shock proof" blender jar instead of plastic. Plastic should remain structurally sound, but it will get hazy.

Comment: The glass jar recommendation confuses mea bit.
I've been chatting with Duronic, and according to them, all glass jars will break if exposed to boiling water.

Comment: @user1361521 I edited my answer just as you commented. Does it make more sense now? Follow the "Oster" link, you'll see plastic and glass jars.

Comment: All I know for sure is that I've blended boiling hot ingredients with my grandmother's old blender with a glass jar probably 50 times. The only part I've ever replaced is the o-ring.

Comment: Sorry @Jolenealaska, I see that Oster sell glass jars that are "heat shock proof". Your answer makes perfect sense.

Comment: That comment is helpful, I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: @user1361521 You might find this particular review of a specific blender jar interesting: [better than the original](http://www.amazon.com/review/R39K0VLTHWOUTJ/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B000JEMUPA&nodeID=1055398&store=home-garden)