# Is pouring hot stock into a blender safe?

Tags: soup, blender

I have a ["ThermoResist Glass Blender"](http://www.kenwoodworld.com/en-int/products/kitchen-machines/chef-and-major-attachments/at358-thermo-resist-glass-blender) attached to a mixer. It is supposed to be safe for blending hot liquids. I'm rather new at this and I'm not sure about how is it supposed to be used and how hot can the liquids be.

Can I prepare stock for soup over a stove top, cook vegetables in it, then pour it directly into the blender's goblet and mix?

Comment: Even though the manufacturer deems hot liquids safe, I'd be cautious. I've worked in the chemistry lab with Pyrex beakers, and thermal shocks can break them. Especially used beakers with scratches. // I'd add the hot liquid to the blender container in the sink, and then put the blender container on the motor using two hands. On on the handle and another on the blender container body with a pot holder.

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/5712/67

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. At the link you provided in the specifications section, it says "Capacity: 1.6 quarts cold liquids; 1.2 quarts hot liquids". The word "hot" is a bit arbitrary, but stock will be fine.

Also, it's called **Thermo**Resist.

Comment: Hi there @Caleb, thank you for your answer. I saw the reference you added. I'm still a little worried. How do you know that stock directly from the pot won't be "too hot"? I couldn't find the safe temperature range for this product anywhere... (including the manual of course).

Comment: Proceed with caution!  Blending hot liquids is absolutely fine, but requires some knowledge and technique. If you dump it in, put the top on, and turn it on, you will have hot liquid all over the place and potentially burn yourself.  You need to allow steam to escape.  Take off the feed tube or small opening in top, place a folded towel over the hole, and start at the lowest speed possible.  You can gradually increase speed, but make sure the jar is not sealed.

Comment: @Daugmented Any water-based liquid in your kitchen isn't going to be at more than a couple of degrees above the boiling point of water. The key piece of physics is that, as you heat a liquid below its boiling point, the energy you're supplying causes the temperature to increase. Once the liquid starts to boil, its temperature remains constant and the energy you're giving it is used to convert the liquid to a gas. You can test this yourself with a pan of water and a thermometer -- just make sure the thermometer bulb isn't touching the pan itself.

Comment: What @moscaf is describing absolutely happens, and actually can be difficult to avoid. It isn't the liquid boiling, but the relatively cool air above the liquid suddenly heating and expanding when you turn the blender on. The pressure can **easily** blow the cover off of the container. Be careful, go slow, and provide a way for the expanding air to escape.

Comment: Thank you @moscafj, this makes a lot of sense and I'll use a towel allowing hot air to escape. Still, why wouldn't they state the maximum temperature the device can handle? The bottom part the blades are fit to, is made of some synthetic material.

Comment: Hi @DanielGriscom, when adding sugar or salt to water I thought that it's maximum temperature rises (e.g. I used this notion thinking that I'm accelerating cooking time in water by adding salt). In addition, I was afraid the vegetables in the stock might reach even higher temperatures.

Comment: @Daugmented  google heat-resistant borosilicate, the glass your blender is made of.  Also see the comment by David above. I believe it is assumed that kitchen blenders will handle liquids at and below the boiling point.